# How to post json string on some specific url

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I want to log amplitude on https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi using the following code:

```
private void LogAmplitude()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var url = "https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        var model = new { user_Id = "userId", event_type = "Event" };
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var data = jss.Serialize(model);
        string parameters = "api_key=" + "apiKey" + "&event=" + data;
        var response = client.UploadString(url, parameters);
    }
}
```

But when I run this method it gives me 400(bad request) error. I have tried posting the data using postman through following url:

```
https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi?api_key=apiKey&event={"user_id":"userId","event_type":"test"}
```

This works totally fine but when I try to post data using the above method it always gives me error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I am doing this kind of work for the very first time. So can anybody help?

Comment: You're trying to send it as a `GET` query request, are you sure these parameters should not be send as the body of a `POST` request ?

Comment: yes you're right, I am also confused. According to amplitude documentation I have to send a post call.

Comment: Shouldn't your `user_Id` in your model be lowercase?

Comment: Sending a post request:
curl --data 'api_key=040062a5d38552315b98302ba4f2f' --data-urlencode 'event=[{"user_id":"john_doe@gmail.com", "event_type":"watch_tutorial", "user_properties":{"Cohort":"Test A"}, "country":"United States", "ip":"127.0.0.1", "time":1396381378123}]' https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation says that you can use `GET`with urlencoded parameters.

Try this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var url = "https://api.amplitude.com/httpapi";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var model = new { user_id = "userId", event_type = "Event" };
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = jss.Serialize(model);
    string parameters = "api_key=" + "apiKey" + "&event=" + System.Uri.EscapeDataString(data);
    var response = client.DownloadString ($"{url}?{parameters}");
}
```